# Isolating external Javascript and preventing pollution?

Tags: javascript, closures

I've got some machine-generated Javascript from a particular game making application that doesn't play nice with closures. I've tried wrapping the entire thing like so:

```
var gameInstance = (function() {

    // Some code that defines stuff

    return {
        initGame: function() {
            _VD1();
        }
     }
})()
```

I'm looking for a way to prevent it from leaking into the global namespace and be able to clean up the entire game afterwards. This particular type of Closure still seems to be causing leaks of dozens of functions. It hides some stuff like the `_VD1` call - but other stuff still manages to leak. What can I look out for / do to prevent this?

Comment: which bits did you add?

Comment: Everything except // Some code that defines stuff; that's where the machine generated code is samwhiched in.

Comment: so the original code just did `_VD1()` ?

Comment: The original code I was using just merely loaded the JS up front and invoked _VD1, yes. But this is causing no hope for clean up and this is a web-app that's continuos.

Comment: If the machine-generated code contains statements like `x = 1` (without `var`) then `x` will be global and you cannot really do much about it, except maybe write something that transforms this code and adds `sandbox.` in front of such statements, where `var sandbox = {}` would be an empty object.

Comment: I thought about pre-processing it; my main concern is these things not being cleaned up upon a second load of the script. 

These assignments might just float away, right?

Comment: how are you inserting the machine-generated code into your javascript file? i mean do you copy and paste it or do you something else?

Comment: Previously, it was in an external JS file and I used require.JS to load it in and execute the init function. Now, I'm trying to wrap it around to lessen the damage it causes but it seems like it's exactly that - there's a bunch of pesky lack of vars kicking around.

Comment: and you load these files from a server and you cannot save them locally to edit them because they are probably always generated on-the-fly and are therefore different each time? is that correct so far?

Comment: You're correct - although programatic processing is possible its not desirable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like the code you're using is declaring a lot of variables without using the `var` keyword.

You could go through it and declare all the variables using the `var` keyword at the top of the outermost function scope where the variable is used.

If you can't modify the other script at all, there isn't much you can do other than make sure that all your own scripts are namespaced properly, so that they can't be interfered with by all the globals that script is declaring/modifying.

Comment: The problem is sometimes multiple of these scripts need to be loaded (it might be executed twice... and there's no way of resetting it's state. :( ). I truly need to be able to contain and kill it.

Comment: Upon quick glance, it looks like this is exactly the issue.

Comment: This is definitely a great way to do it. Keeps all variables and functions contained within the closure. @VaughanHilts Are you saying you will need multiple game instances active at the same time? If so, can you do `var instance1 = new gameInstance;`?

Comment: @AndrewHuth The problem is multiple game instances might be loaded in page succession - this is a web app that dosen't refresh for a bit. I need to prevent the globals from these machine generated files from conflicting.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you're trying to keep some javascript sandboxed, it may be possible to achieve this using an iframe. This is untested but might serve as inspiration;

```
var sb = document.createElement('iframe');
document.body.appendChild(sb);
sb.document.write('
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<script>
gameInstance = (function() {

    // Some code that defines stuff

    return {
        initGame: function() {
            _VD1();
        }
     }
})()

</script>
</body>
</html>');

var gameInstance = sb.gameInstance;
```

Comment: Why append code to the document as text instead of just using closures?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe http://jqueryboilerplate.com/ gives an inspiration for you

```
// the semi-colon before function invocation is a safety net against concatenated
// scripts and/or other plugins which may not be closed properly.
;(function ( $, window, document, undefined ) {

})( jQuery, window, document );
```